# Password field regular expression

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-replace

OK so I'm trying to preg_match a string (an entered password) with a regular expression but after hours of reading/watching regexp info on the internet I still don't understand it..

I currently have:
    '/^[A-Z]^[a-z]+$/'

The password must:

Be between 8 and 16 characters.
Contain at least 1 Upper case letter
Contain at least 1 Lower case letter
Contain at least 1 number

If you could also include a regular expression with all of the above requirements but also with
Contain at least 1 symbol

for my own learning I'd be grateful.
Please try and explain your Regular Expression so that maybe I can understand it. Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned, I've read up for hours and watched videos on YouTube but still can't find what I'm looking for

Comment: If you're having trouble with regex, try the site regexr.com, this will allow you to dynamically evaluate your regex while typing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Between 8 and 16 characters:

   ```
   ^.{8,16}$
   ```
2. At least one uppercase letter

   ```
   (?=.*[A-Z])
   ```
3. At least one lowercase letter

   ```
   (?=.*[a-z])
   ```
4. At least one number

   ```
   (?=.*\d)
   ```

Putting it together:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,16}$
```

If you want a Unicode-aware variant (probably futile with PHP, I know):

```
^(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Nd}).{8,16}$
```

This works by having a number of [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the beginning, each of which checking one desired property of your string. Lookahead assertions check whether the part in parentheses *could* match at this position, but won't advance the *actual* match position in the string. The actual match here just makes sure the length matches your requirement.

Note though, that this should essentially be computationally the same as several regex matches checking for each of the properties. It's just packaged in a single regex.

Oh, and at least one symbol can be checked likewise with `(?=.*[,.!?])` or something similar, depending on what you consider a symbol.

Comment: +1, clear and straight to the point.

Comment: You've just taught me more in 10 seconds of reading than the whole of Google and YouTube. Thanks.

Comment: George: Look though http://regular-expressions.info. It's an awesome site for learning how regexes work. That and practice taught me pretty much all I know right now (and a bit of SO).

Comment: ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,16}$
>> Not calculate uppercase
^(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Nd}).{8,16}$
>> not calculate any charactor

http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ here i test it

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I was wondering if a RegExp can be made to act like an input mask I.E: for a date the string would need to equal 00/00/0000 where 0 = any integer? Thanks.

Comment: George, ask another question for that. Comments are mostly for clarification and not or extended discussion nor for asking more questions.

Comment: +1 Good explanation. But instead of the dot-star in the lookaheads, it is better to use a more precise expression (which is more efficient), i.e. instead of: `(?=.*[A-Z])` use: `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` and instead of: `(?=.*\d)` use: `(?=\D*\d)` etc. This eliminates a lot of backtracking. Also, why not write the regex natively in free-spacing mode with all your excellent documentation built-in. Just sayin'